# How might one create an extra worker thread for a single threaded GUI application?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, vcl, boost-thread

I am currently developing new features for an existing VCL application. The application creates charts and static images using a thirdparty package called TeeChart.
There is one instance where I have to load in 2 million data points to create a static image chart. However, this takes a while to load and the user can't do anything in the application
until it is completed. Therefore I would prefer to create a worker thread to process the data points so the GUI doesn't freeze.

The method `setData()` sets the following member variables, which the VCL component will then go on and use to create the Chart:

```
// Holds the Y position for the image (columns)
DynamicArray<double>* mpda_XValues;

// Holds the colour for the corresponding element in the x and y
// position
DynamicArray<double>* mpda_YValues;

// Holds the z position for the image (rows)
DynamicArray<double>* mpda_ZValues;
```

What things should I consider when creating a worker thread?

How might I create the thread using boost when all the data processing occurs in one method `setData(){...}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the VCL, it might be a good idea to look at the TThread class. Create an inherited class from this, and use the Synchronize method when communicating with your main thread. You can try looking at: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Defining_Thread_Objects

Answer (score 1):

You obviously will want to look at the [boost thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread.html) library.

This is (probably) more complicated than you think. Converting a synchronous function that has side effects to an async function is non-trivial. Some things to consider:

- Will callers of setData be able to
  handle the "setting" operation not
  being done when the function returns?
- How will you ensure the background setData operation during shutdown, if one is on going?
- How will you handle shared state
  between your GUI thread and the
  setData thread, as to not cause race
  conditions?
- Will you need a "notification"
  mechanism, so the GUI thread can
  refresh (or do something) when the
  background setData completes?
- What happens if someone calls setData
  while a background setData operation
  is pending?